# Using OpenCV 2.3 with Qt in QtCreator

Tags: visual-studio-2008, qt, opencv, mingw, qt-creator

as the release of OpenCV 2.3 is finally out, I wanted to compile and install this latest release on my system. As I often work with Qt and the QtCreator I of course wanted to be able to use it in my Qt projects. I've tried several methods now for some hours but always get errors:

**First try: Compiling OpenCV 2.3 with WITH_QT**

First I wanted to do it just like I did with the 2.2 release which worked fine for me. For this I followed this guide: http://knowtheabc.wordpress.com/2011/02/25/windows-opencv-and-qt-creator/

- Downloaded the source code
- Set up CMake and told it to create MInGW Makefiles and specified the paths to the `g++.exe`, `gcc.exe` and `qmake.exe` in my C:\Qt... paths, checked WITH_QT and generated Makefiles for a release.
- Built and installed it in a shell using `mingw32-make` and `mingw32-make install`

After this was completed successfully, I just needed to add the paths to my ".pro" file and was able to build some nice software that uses OpenCV (back at the time where I used the 2.2 release). Basically the last part is described here: http://knowtheabc.wordpress.com/2011/02/25/opencv-in-qt/

So I tried the same with the 2.3 release which compiled successfully just as with the old release. It even builds my example program but as soon as I execute it, it closes again and returns: `-1073741515`

**Second try: Using the pre-built OpenCV superpack using MinGW**

As the first method didn't work I tried to use the pre-build versions. Though these don't have the WITH_QT enabled, I still wanted to try.

So I downloaded the superpack, extracted and put it somewhere. I then wanted to do the same as I did before and added the paths to the include folder and the dlls to my ".pro" file:

```
INCLUDEPATH+= C:/workspace/opencv/OpenCV2.3/build/include
LIBS+= C:/workspace/opencv/OpenCV2.3/build/x64/mingw/bin/*.dll
```

As compiler I used the MinGW compiler that comes with the current Qt SDK. But this crashes while building:

```
C:/workspace/opencv/OpenCV2.3/build/x64/mingw/bin/libopencv_calib3d230.dll: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make[1]: *** [release\CoinDetector.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make: *** [release] Error 2
```

**Third try: Just like the second, but with using the VC2008 compiler**

I tried the same thing with the vc2008 compiler that comes with the Qt SDK as well. So I selected the compiler and adapted the path in the ".pro" file to use:

```
LIBS+= C:/workspace/opencv/OpenCV2.3/build/x64/vc9/bin/*.dll
```

But this also crashes with an error that it can't read the dll:

```
C:/workspace/opencv/OpenCV2.3/build/x64/vc9/bin/opencv_calib3d230.dll : fatal error LNK1107: Ungültige oder beschädigte Datei: Lesen bei 0x2F0 nicht möglich.
```

---

So here my settings:

- Win7 Professional x64
- Latest Qt SDK installed (4.7.3)
- OpenCV 2.3 release

***Does anybody have an idea what might be wrong here? Would be glad for any help!***

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just got my QT 4.7.3 to work with OpenCV2.3. Unfortunately I had to install VC++2008 Express Edition and the CDB Debugger from Microsoft (both are freebies from Microsoft).
The good part is that I can now develop for Opencv in both IDE, VS 2008, and Qt Creator.

These are the settings of my .pro file:

```
INCLUDEPATH += C:/OpenCV2.3/build/include
INCLUDEPATH += C:/OpenCV2.3/build/include/opencv

LIBS += C:/OpenCV2.3/build/x86/vc9/lib/opencv_calib3d230.lib
LIBS += C:/OpenCV2.3/build/x86/vc9/lib/opencv_contrib230.lib
LIBS += C:/OpenCV2.3/build/x86/vc9/lib/opencv_core230.lib
LIBS += C:/OpenCV2.3/build/x86/vc9/lib/opencv_features2d230.lib
LIBS += C:/OpenCV2.3/build/x86/vc9/lib/opencv_flann230.lib
LIBS += C:/OpenCV2.3/build/x86/vc9/lib/opencv_highgui230.lib
LIBS += C:/OpenCV2.3/build/x86/vc9/lib/opencv_imgproc230.lib
LIBS += C:/OpenCV2.3/build/x86/vc9/lib/opencv_objdetect230.lib
LIBS += C:/OpenCV2.3/build/x86/vc9/lib/opencv_video230.lib
```

Remember, select the MSVC compiler in your Projects Settings

I have tried I don't know how many different approaches to make it work with MinGW, but not the right one so far. 
I'm also in Windows 7 64 bits...but I am developing for 32 bits,  I suppose that if I use the x64 libraries I might get 64 bit projects to work.

Good luck,

Andres

Comment: well as a student I have the complete Visual Studio 2008 installed since I get it via MSDNAA. So you use the pre-built version but simply include the lib-files instead of the dlls? That would be worth a try... thanks so far

Comment: OK i just tried your stuff and it no longer gives errors while compiling... yet now I get the same error as I did in the mingw version I compiled myself in "First try" - the return value of: -1073741515... so the whole problem seems to boil down to fixing that error, then it should work with Visual Studio compiler and MinGW as well...

Comment: Did you modify your PATH environment variable? Mine looks like hell, because I kept adding until it worked: Specially c:\OPenCV2.3\build\x86\vc9\bin; C:\opencv2.3\build\x86\mingw\bin;c:\mingw\bin;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studion 9.0\VC\bin...

Comment: You were right with the missing dlls in the path-variable. It had them all during compiling but couldn't find them while executing and therefore crashed.. thank you! Works fine now!

Answer (score 1):

Evident,

I got as far as the -1073741515 error also today.
It turned out that the problem was related to the Qt dlls which I had in the release folder.... I was still using the mingw32 versions and not the msvc2008 ones. So I copied the msvc2008 dll files to my Release folder and I finally managed to run my Qt app.